# setTimeout order

Tags: html, css, settimeout

I am having trouble with `setTimeout()`, I guess.

You can visit my webpage to see where I am at: http://verbum.xtrweb/soon.php

The problem is that i have 2 text fields.

1. "Verbum" with `id="Verbum"`
2. "Forget about single searches" with `id="forget"`

I want to apply a fade in effect after the tiny dictionaries fall (please see my site link above so you understand). I have changed the function's name and variables too, but the only thing that happens is that only one of the texts fades in, and it depends on the order of which one is below the other. The one that does not fade in does not even appear. Hope you understood and find and anwser. Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var opac = 0.0;
  var alpha = 0;

  function init() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("Verbum");
    elem.style.display = 'inline';
    elem.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + alpha + ")";
    elem.style.opacity = opac;

    setTimeout("fadein()", 8500);
  }

  function fadein() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("Verbum");

    opac = opac + 0.1;
    alpha = parseInt(opac * 100);
    elem.style.opacity = opac;
    elem.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + alpha + ")";

    if (opac < 1.0) {
      //Change the 50 to adjust the speed. The higher the number, the slower the fade
      setTimeout("fadein()", 30);
    }

  }
  window.onload=init;
</script>
```

Here is the second `<script>` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var opac = 0.0;
  var alpha = 0;

  function init() {
    var eleme = document.getElementById("forget");
    eleme.style.display = 'inline';
    eleme.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + alpha + ")";
    eleme.style.opacity = opac;

    setTimeout("fadein()", 7500);
  }

  function fadein() {
    var eleme = document.getElementById("forget");

    opac = opac + 0.1;
    alpha = parseInt(opac * 100);
    eleme.style.opacity = opac;
    eleme.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + alpha + ")";

    if (opac < 1.0) {
      // Change the 50 to adjust the speed. The higher the number, the slower the fade
      setTimeout("fadein()", 30);
    }

  }

  window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Comment: A quick note: easy to read code is more likely to facilitate a solution. Take note of the particular changes made to indentation and spacing, as they greatly improve code readability. Also, just a guess, but you can't set two `onload` functions that way. Combine both of them into a single init function.

Comment: Your site link doesn't work?

Comment: http://verbum.xtrweb/soon.php still does not work

Comment: totally right. its: verbum.xtrweb.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you can only assign one function to `window.onload` as a time. The last one will always take precedence over the first ones.

Instead of using `window.onload`, you can use `window.addEventListener` to tell the browser to run your code when the page loads. You can use it like this.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var eleme = document.getElementById("forget");
    eleme.style.display = 'inline';
    eleme.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + alpha + ")";
    eleme.style.opacity = opac;

    setTimeout("fadein()", 7500);
}, false);
```

You will need to copy and paste this twice, one for "forget" and one for "Verbum".

Also, I'd suggest changing the names of your `fadein` functions, or pass the element to be faded as an argument. Otherwise your code will simply run the last fadein function and either "forget" or "Verbum" will work correctly, and the other will not.

Comment: Further to my answer, I'd strongly recommend you look at using the jQuery library. It's very easy to handle "on load" events, and fade things in and out. For example, `$('#forget').fadeIn();`.

Comment: Yet, i need to add a third element, and i have changed the function id, but this last element does not fade in, just pops up as usual.

Comment: Double-check all ID's. Make sure you're targeting the right elements.

Comment: triple checked IDs, and the third element is still not fading in

Comment: Try using this code to fade in things instead (I notice you're already using jQuery). Also, instead of using `visibility:hidden;` use `display:none;` http://pastebin.com/GmxSvm2i If this doesn't work, I'd recommend starting a new question (try and simplify the example code as much as possible).